# MicroBlink BlinkId not working in iPad Air

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ocr, microblink

I've implemented MicroBlink BlinkID for scanning MRZ on ID cards. Both my app, and the sample on the site works on our iPhones, but we've tried both of these apps on our iPad Airs (2 different iPads) and the didOutputResults method never gets called on the iPad, although it works perfectly fine for the iPhone (5s, 6, 6 plus) (identical configuration).

I don't even know where to start debugging so any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the frame in the default view controller. If I just ignore the frame and put the card near the screen, it works perfectly.